# Read Data from Web.xml using class file

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets, web.xml

i want use read data from XML context-param using java class file not servlet. for establish a connection

Comment: It's incredibly unclear what you are trying to achieve and what your question is.

Comment: i want to trying read data from web.xml using class file not servlet give me some to do it . bcoz getServletContext()work only in servlets

Comment: How can I read context parameter/web.xml values in a non-servlet java file?

Comment: Is this class (which wants to read the web.xml) a part of your web project or its an independent code?

Comment: part of web project bt its only a class no servlet AdityaKeyal